# How to read the range indicator in IL-2 Sturmovik 1946

Tags: il2-sturmovik-1946

How do I read the range indicator that is placed next to aircraft? It says 5.03, or 1.23, or 0.54. In what units are they? Feet, meters, miles, kilometers? Or does 1.00 mean that it's the optimum gun range?

Comment: Kilometers probably. I seriously doubt you were 0.54 feet from another aircraft!

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry. See my edits above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distances are in Kilometres.

www.mission4today.com has an excellent beginners [tutorial](http://www.mission4today.com/index.php?name=Knowledge_Base&op=show&kid=431) which also goes into optimum gun range, or convergence number.